# Postgres protected access

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to configure my Postgres instance so that only the local machine and my machine (over internet) should be able to access the database. The `postgresql.conf` file has parameter `listen_addresses` which can be used to set the list of ip addresses to which access is granted.

So I set it as `listen_addresses 'localhost,a.b.c.d'`
which mean it will grant access to `localhost` and `a.b.c.d` which is, say my ip address. But in this case it just grant access to localhost.

`listen_addresses 'a.b.c.d'` also does not work.
I double checked the internet ip address but it is correct.
I tried

```
listen_addresses 'localhost'         // works only for local machine.
listen_addresses '*'                 // works for both local and my machine
listen_addresses 'localhost,a.b.c.d' // does not work for my machine
listen_addresses 'a.b.c.d'           // does not work for my machine
```

So am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 2):

You have understood the concept of listen addresses wrong.

`listen_addresses` is the list of IP addresses of the interfaces on the server running PostgreSQL, which can be used to connect to the PostgreSQL service.

So, for example, your PostgreSQL server has the IP address `192.168.10.1`, you specify:

```
listen_addresses 'localhost,192.168.10.1';
```

This means that all clients that can reach IP address `192.168.10.1` can connect to the PostgreSQL server.

If you want to restrict connections by connecting client's IP address, then you have two options:

1. Use PostgreSQL's host-based access mechanism to apply IP restrictions on connections [using `pg_hba.conf`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html). See [client authentication](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/client-authentication.html).
2. Add firewall rules that prevent connections to PostgreSQL port from all IP addresses except the ones you want to allow.

Comment: Where `(1)` means `pg_hba.conf`; edited answer.